# SQL: Function select column into variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to select two columns in two variables how can i do it, here the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkUser(pUserName VARCHAR2, pCountry VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER 

IS
   vUsername VARCHAR2(100); 
   vCountry VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
   SELECT Person.Username INTO vUsername
   FROM Person
   WHERE Person.Username = pUserName;
   EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       vUsername := NULL;

   SELECT Person.Country INTO vCountry
   FROM Person
   WHERE Person.Country = pCountry;
   EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      vCountry := NULL;

   IF vUsername IS NULL OR vCountry IS NULL THEN
      RETURN False;
   ELSE
      RETURN True;
   END IF;
END checkUser;
```

Can i do that? I am new in SQL.

Comment: so, what's your question ?  what error are you getting ?

Comment: Pretty sure you will have a problem if two Persons have the same country (ORA-01422) because you will attempt to store a list of countries in a VARCHAR2. What is your function supposed to do anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do, the following code will give you the desired result. Note that `RETURN NUMBER` you are using is not right if you need to return strings `'True'` or `'False'` .

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Checkuser(pusername VARCHAR2,
                                     pcountry  VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_count NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(1)
    INTO   v_count
    FROM   person p
    WHERE  p.username = pusername
           AND p.country = pcountry;

    IF v_count = 0 THEN
      RETURN 'False';
    ELSE
      RETURN 'True';
    END IF;
END checkuser;
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting more than a single column is not much more complicated than what you are doing at the moment :

```
SELECT p.Username,p.Country INTO vUsername, vCountry  
   FROM Person p
   WHERE p.Username = pUserName AND p.Country = pCountry;
```

Just separate the columns with ',' after the `SELECT` and after the `INTO`.

Off topic, you need to make sure you don't have multiple records corresponding to your argument username and country otherwise you will have an error attempting to store a list of data in scalar variables.